# Custom workflow: Failed on Start (retrying)

Tags: 2007, workflow

I created a workflow project with WSPBuilder and everything worked fine. I then moved the workflow to our main project and added all needed references. However when I try to couple the workflow I always get the message: "Failed on start (retrying)" when it's being executed.
In my logs I find following error:

> 0x14E4    Windows SharePoint Services
>     Workflow Infrastructure
>     936l    High        Engine RunWorkflow:
>   System.Workflow.ComponentModel.Compiler.WorkflowValidationFailedException:
>   The workflow failed validation.     at
>   System.Workflow.Runtime.WorkflowDefinitionDispenser.ValidateDefinition(Activity
>   root, Boolean isNewType, ITypeProvider
>   typeProvider)     at
>   System.Workflow.Runtime.WorkflowDefinitionDispenser.LoadRootActivity(Type
>   workflowType, Boolean
>   createDefinition, Boolean
>   initForRuntime)     at
>   System.Workflow.Runtime.WorkflowDefinitionDispenser.MruCache.GetOrGenerateDefinition(Type
>   type, String xomlText, String
>   rulesText, Byte[] md5Codes, Boolean
>   initForRuntime, Boolean& exist)     at
>   System.Workflow.Runtime.WorkflowDefinitionDispenser.GetRootActivity(Type
>   workflowType, Boolean createNew,
>   Boolean initForRuntime)     at
>   System.Workflow.Runtime.WorkflowRuntime.Initializ...

But the validation should be correct since it worked before ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Copying over the workflow definition and adding the referenced assemblies isn't enough, since your main project will most likely be of a different type and won't be recognized as a"workflow project". You can solve this by manually editing the project file. To do this:

- unload the project (right-click on
  the project node in the solution
  explorer -> unload project).
- right-click again to edit the csproj
  file add following line in the first
  PropertyGroup element, e.g. under
  ProjectGuid element. These are the [project type Guids](http://www.mztools.com/articles/2008/mz2008017.aspx) for windows C# and Workflow C#

  <ProjectTypeGuids>{14822709-B5A1-4724-98CA-57A101D1B079};{FAE04EC0-301F-11D3-BF4B-00C04F79EFBC}</ProjectTypeGuids>
- find following fragment under the
  root Project node, usually at the
  bottom of the csproj file:

  <Import Project=”$(MSBuildBinPath)\Microsoft.CSharp.targets” />

and add following line under it:

```
<Import Project=”$(MSBuildExtensionsPath)\Microsoft\Windows Workflow Foundation\v3.5\Workflow.Targets” />
```

Comment: Works like a charm now